# How to make a pipe in c++

Tags: c++, pipe, pseudocode

I'm looking at the code for a c++ program which pipes the contents of a file to more. I don't quite understand it, so I was wondering if someone could write pseudocode for a c++ program that pipes something to something else? Why is it necessary to use fork?

Comment: You have to use fork since piping is a form of parallelizing your program, and if you don't fork then it won't work properly.

Answer (score 6):

```
create pipe
fork process
if child:
  connect pipe to stdin
  exec more
write to pipe
```

You need `fork()` so that you can replace stdin of the child before calling, and so that you don't wait for the process before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

You will find your answer precisely [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it necessary to use fork?

When you run a pipeline from the shell, eg.

```
$ ls | more
```

what happens? The shell runs two processes (one for `ls`, one for `more`). Additionally, the output (STDOUT) of `ls` is connected to the input (STDIN) of `more`, by a pipe.

Note that `ls` and `more` don't need to know anything about pipes, they just write to (and read from) their STDOUT (and STDIN) respectively. Further, because they're likely to do normal *blocking* reads and writes, it's essential that they can run concurrently. Otherwise `ls` could just fill the pipe buffer and block forever before `more` gets a chance to consume anything.

> ... pipes something to something else ...

Note also that aside from the concurrency argument, if your *something else* is another program (like `more`), it *must* run in another process. You create this process using `fork`. If you just run `more` in the *current* process (using `exec`), it would *replace* your program.

---

In general, you *can* use a pipe without `fork`, but you'll just be communicating within your own process. This means you're either doing non-blocking operations (perhaps in a synchronous co-routine setup), or using multiple threads.